react app upon deployment shows WHITESCREEN in vercel

i am deploying my react app in vercel, the server side is running and wokring however the frontend is not working and kept showing this error, which is whitescreen, i have tried the remove node_modeulse, reinstalled the modules, i am using 18node in vercel
this is my vercel code
{
"version": 2,
"builds": [
    {
        "src": "package.json",
        "use": "@vercel/static-build"
    }
],
"routes": [
    {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "/index.html"
    }
]}

Then this is my routes


import './App.css';
import './transition.css'
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';


import Home from './public/pages/Home';
import Login from './public/pages/Login';
import Signup from './public/pages/Signup';

import ForgotPassword from './public/pages/ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword';
import Verification from './public/pages/ForgotPassword/Verification';
import ChangePassword from './public/pages/ForgotPassword/ChangePassword';

import Cart from './client/pages/Cart/Cart';
import Checkout from './client/pages/Transactions/Checkout';
import OrderHistory from './client/pages/Transactions/OrderHistory';
import Shop from './client/pages/Cart/shop';
import UserProfile from './client/pages/Transactions/UserProfile';

import Dashboard from './admin/Dashboard';
import Orders from './admin/pages/Orders';
import Payments from './admin/pages/Payments';
import Shipments from './admin/pages/Shipments';
import Products from './admin/pages/Products';
import Inventory from './admin/pages/Inventory';
import Reports from './admin/pages/Reports';
import Users from './admin/pages/Users';
import Settings from './admin/pages/Settings';
import Sales from './admin/pages/Sales';
import Transactions from './admin/pages/Transaction';
import AdminHistory from './admin/pages/AdminHistory';


function App() {
  const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <TransitionGroup>
      <CSSTransition
        key={location.key}
        classNames="fade"
        timeout={300}
      >
        <Routes location={location}>
          {/* Redirect any undefined route to Home TEST EDIT */}
          <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
          <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
          <Route path="/checkout" element={<Checkout />} />
          <Route path="/user/purchase" element={<OrderHistory />} />
          <Route path='/admin/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path='/shop' element={<Shop />} />
          <Route path='/admin/orders' element={<Orders />} />
          <Route path='/admin/payments' element={<Payments />} />
          <Route path='/admin/shipments' element={<Shipments />} />
          <Route path='/admin/products' element={<Products />} />
          <Route path='/admin/inventory' element={<Inventory />} />
          <Route path='/admin/reports' element={<Reports />} />
          <Route path='/admin/manage-users' element={<Users />} />
          <Route path='/admin/profile' element={<Settings />} />
          <Route path='/forgot-password' element={<ForgotPassword />} />
          <Route path='/verify' element={<Verification />} />
          <Route path='/change-password' element={<ChangePassword />} />
          <Route path="/user" element={<UserProfile />} />
          <Route path='/admin/reports/sales' element={<Sales />} />
          <Route path='/admin/reports/order-history' element={<AdminHistory />} />
          <Route path='/admin/reports/transactions' element={<Transactions />} />

        </Routes>
      </CSSTransition>
    </TransitionGroup>
  );
}

export default App;



i did put this in my enviroment in vercel


It looks like the environment variable PUBLIC_URL wasn't correctly replaced.

do i need to replace it with my domain?

Probably yes. The URLs in the screenshot look wrong.

its defualt in vercel deployment sir @jabaa

Open the first screenshot. Do you see %PUBLIC_URL%? That's wrong. It's not in the posted code, so nobody can help.

@jabaa i did remove the $PUBLIC$ on the index. but it stil show. i did rebuild
